# Integral with the derivative of the Dirac's Delta

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

> Solve $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \ \delta'' (x) \ \text{exp} \left( \dfrac{2}{1-x} \right)$.

Hi. I'm asked to solve the previous integral. I've tried to integrate by parts twice:

$\displaystyle \left. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \ \delta'' (x) \ \text{exp} \left( \dfrac{2}{1-x} \right) = \delta' (x) \ \text{exp} \left( \dfrac{2}{1-x} \right) \right|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta' (x) \dfrac{d}{dx} \text{exp} \left( \dfrac{2}{1-x} \right)$.

If the first integral goes to 0, then the result is

$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \text{exp} \left( \dfrac{2}{1-x} \right) (0)$,

which is what I want to obtain. Therefore, I'm not sure if the first term of the integration by parts is, in fact, 0.

Comment: What's the value of $\delta'(x)$ when $x\neq 0$?

Comment: The symbol $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta''(x)e^{2/(1-x)}\,dx$ is not an integral.  It is abusive notation for a linear functional that maps any test function $f$ (i.e., $f\in C_C^\infty$) into $f''(0)$.  Note that $e^{2/(1-x)}$ is not a test function.  However, the distribution $\delta''_0$ has compact support on $\{0\}$.  So, the result is still $\left.\left(\frac{d2}{dx^2}e^{2/(1-x)}\right)\right|_{x=0}$.